# How to get JSON responce to HTTP Request

Tags: iphone, ios, json, cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest

WebService is capable of giving response in XML, Plain Text and JSon.

I can successfully get response in XML.
My concern is, how one can get Response in JSon format (not XML or plain text).

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
   NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *array = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

    NSString *success = [array valueForKey:@"Successful"];
    NSString *token = [array valueForKey:@"Token"];
}
```

Above is the code for handling the response (Which i did assume JSon, but it was XML).
Hence the app is crashing.

Following is the responce which i am getting:

`<AuthenticatedUser xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XYZCOMPANY.ABC.DataContracts.Mobile" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ErrorMsg i:nil="true"/><Successful>true</Successful><Token>MHlc8yKBgghjkfPHZ2oOvabvMWA=</Token></AuthenticatedUser>`

Comment: Refered it, but it gives me responce in XML. I want to get it in JSon Format.

Comment: Well you have to give us more information, Lick which webservice? just saying that some thing does work with out saying what is isn;'t very easy to solve. I know that some webservice look at the accept header of the HTTP request while other requere a GET parameter to return JSON.

Comment: Still you will hace to ask the person who build the webservice how to set the output to JSON since there is no one way of default way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not hitting the wrong endpoint you probably need to set the http accept header to "application/json" like @rckoenes said. What you can also do is try to hit the service using CURL or even your web browser to see if the json service is running.

Here is the code it is working for me for requesting a local JSON service created by SOAPUI:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]
                        initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:SERVERURL]
                        cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                        timeoutInterval: 10];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                        initWithRequest:request
                        delegate:self
                        startImmediately:YES];
if(!connection) {
        DLog(@"connection failed");
} else {
        DLog(@"Connection succeeded");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the webservice is written...

http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json

Comment: Web service i am talking about is giving me XML response. And it also gives JSon (with jQuery using phoneGap), I am trying to make Native iPhone App. So, any specific method which can respond the request in JSon format.

Answer (score -1):

Import JSON framework in your application.
[Refer this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html)